# Ubuntu 12.10 is increasingly slower until compiz is restarted through change in ccsm

Tags: 12.10, compiz, ccsm

After installing Ubuntu 12.10 on my machine I've noticed that it grows increasingly slower and slower until I change a setting in compiz config settings manager which somehow restarts compiz and leaves my computer superfast again. Then, after another hour, the computer is so slow that it takes 10 seconds to see all the windows in the window expo view (super+w).

I've tried some of the regular suggestions about how to fix this but nothing helps for more than one hour. Any suggestions?

Computer: Dell Latitude E6420 with core i5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled my computer with 12.4 instead hoping that the LTS would solve my problems. And it did, it's been working for over <strike>two</strike> <strike>five</strike> eight hours and still feels quick and snappy.